# Using SQL Server string functions to extract the values

Tags: sql-server, mysql, sql-server-2008

I have a column `transactionID` which has data in this format: `3368/00392224/000/00`.

I have to extract data from this column in to four columns like:

```
Column name    Data
A   3368
B   00392224
C   000
D   00
```

I have to achieve this using SQL Server string functions to extract the values with good efficiency. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You also have a MySQL tag. Are both your source and destination tables of the same RDBMS?

Comment: Are you only ever handling one row at a time? How should two rows look?

Comment: Also, can you please pick a platform? It is unlikely you will get a single answer that works for both MySQL and SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you can use a combination of SUBSTRING (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and CHARINDEX(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
  CHARINDEX('/',MyColumn) AS P1,
  CHARINDEX('/',MyColumn,CHARINDEX('/',MyColumn)+1) AS P2,
  CHARINDEX('/',MyColumn,CHARINDEX('/',MyColumn,CHARINDEX('/',MyColumn)+1)+1) AS P3
FROM MyTable;
```

This will give you the positions of the three `/` characters.
To split the fields use this:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(transactionId,1,P1-1) AS A,
  SUBSTRING(transactionId,P1+1,P2-P1-1) AS B,
  SUBSTRING(transactionId,P2+1,P3-P2-1) AS C,
  SUBSTRING(transactionId,P3+1,LEN(transactionId)) AS D
FROM(
SELECT 
  CHARINDEX('/',transactionId) AS P1,
  CHARINDEX('/',transactionId,CHARINDEX('/',transactionId)+1) AS P2,
  CHARINDEX('/',transactionId,CHARINDEX('/',transactionId,CHARINDEX('/',transactionId)+1)+1) AS P3,
  transactionId
FROM dbo.MyTable
  )X;
```

Finally, if you are on version 2005 or later, you can use UNPIVOT ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) to separate the values into multiple rows:

```
SELECT U.*
FROM (
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(transactionId,1,P1-1) AS A,
  SUBSTRING(transactionId,P1+1,P2-P1-1) AS B,
  SUBSTRING(transactionId,P2+1,P3-P2-1) AS C,
  SUBSTRING(transactionId,P3+1,LEN(transactionId)) AS D
FROM(
SELECT 
  CHARINDEX('/',transactionId) AS P1,
  CHARINDEX('/',transactionId,CHARINDEX('/',transactionId)+1) AS P2,
  CHARINDEX('/',transactionId,CHARINDEX('/',transactionId,CHARINDEX('/',transactionId)+1)+1) AS P3,
  transactionId
FROM dbo.MyTable
  )X
  )Y
UNPIVOT (Data for ColumnName IN(A,B,C,D))U ;
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2705e/9/0)

Now, performance is another topic altogether. SQL Server is inherently bad at string manipulation. You can speed this up significantly by using a [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) String-Split function.

Answer (score 3):

**For SQL Server**

Assuming you will always have exactly four values, you can use a sneaky trick with [`PARSENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) - if you are okay with its limitations it can be much less clunky than more cumbersome parsing methods.

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(ID INT, transactionId VARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x VALUES(1, '000/334/1123232/3434');
INSERT @x VALUES(2, '343/224/114/32325665454');

;WITH x(ID, A,B,C,D) AS
(
  SELECT ID, PARSENAME(t,4), PARSENAME(t,3), PARSENAME(t,2), PARSENAME(t,1)
    FROM (SELECT ID, t = REPLACE(transactionId,'/','.') FROM @x) AS y
)
SELECT ID, [Column name], [Data] FROM x
UNPIVOT ([Data] FOR [Column name] IN (A,B,C,D)) AS up;
```

Results:

```
ID  Column name  Data
--  -----------  ------------
1   A            000
1   B            334
1   C            1123232
1   D            3434 
2   A            343
2   B            224
2   C            114 
2   D            32325665454
```

Answer (score -2):

Use below code to get desire result

DECLARE @String varchar(max),
  @Splitchar char(1),
  @Xmlvalue xml

set @String = '3368/00392224/000/00'
set @Splitchar = '/'

SELECT @Xmlvalue = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <s> ' + REPLACE(@String,@Splitchar,'</s> <s>') + ' </s>   </root> ')

SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @Xmlvalue.nodes('/root/s') T(c)

[image: Query Result]